# Getting total and average call duration per user

Tags: mysql, sql

Give a table initially with data as follows:

```
ID  |user       |Contact   |Duration
1    asif        11         00
2    bob         22         65
3    cena        33         00
4    asif        44         00
5    cena        33         00
6    cena        33         00
7    bob         55         43
8    asif        44         33
9    bob         66         00
```

I would to have the number of distinct contacts for each user, I used the following:

```
select user, count(distinct contact) from table group by user;
```

which provided me the following output:

```
|A      |count
 asif    2
 bob     3
 cena    1
```

Now, I would like to have the total duration by user, as well as the ACD (Average call duration = `duration_total / count of contact with duration > 0`). For example:

```
  | asif'ACD = (33+00+00)/1 = 33  | 
  | bob'ACD = (65+43+00) /2 = 54  | 
  | cena'ACD = (00+00+00 /0 = 0   |
```

The final result that I am looking for would be

```
|user      |count   |duration_total    |ACD
 asif       2        33                 33
 bob        3        108                54
 cena       1        00                 00
```

Could someone please give me some advice about what SQL command I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` with `case`.  One thing to look out for is not dividing by zero, hence the subquery:

```
select user, 
       contactcount,
       duration,
       case when durationcount = 0 then 0 else duration/durationcount end
from (
    select user, 
           count(distinct contact) contactcount,
           sum(duration) duration,
           sum(case when duration > 0 then 1 else 0 end) durationcount
    from table 
    group by user
) t
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/257b81/2)